# Java classes are in the same package (different directories) but they can't access each other

Tags: java, package, intellij-idea

I have two files:

MyProject/src/main/java/foo_package/bar_package/MainClass.java
MyProject/src/gen/java/foo_package/bar_package/OtherClass.java

In both of those classes the very first line is:

```
package foo_package.bar_package;
```

If I call:

```
OtherClass foo = new OtherClass();
```

It cannot resolve symbol OtherClass. Why is that?

What I've tried:

- Rebuild project
- Invalidate cache/Restart
- Reimport project
- Delete .iml files and .idea folder and import everything again

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a problem with the path of the last class:

> MyProject/src/**main**/java/foo_package/bar_package/MainClass.java 
>   MyProject/src/**gen**/java/foo_package/bar_package/OtherClass.java

If your classes have the same package (package starts after `../java/`) but they are not part of the java build path, then the IDE won't recognise them as valid.

Try moving your `OtherClass.java` to the package where the `MainClass.java` is. Doing this should eventually solve your problem.

PS: be aware about the source folders of your project (most of the time `main` is the source folder by default and it's enough but there may be other source folders, generally added manually).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your IDEA source folder is `java`, not `src` (for both `java` folders inside `/gen/` and inside `/main`).
The sources root is marked as a blue directory in "Project" window (`Alt + 1`).